# how to check what php fpm is doing?

Tags: nginx, php

We have php-fpm setup on nginx, and all is working fine as far as the end-user experience is concerned, we use varnish infront of it all so usually the load is low on varnish's backend.

however sometimes when we run top, we see that php-fpm process is eating up memory, specially after varnish restarts.

Now what i am trying to do is perhaps see what part of php that php-fpm is running, is there anyways to monitor exactly what php-fpm is doing at that very moment?

a list of monitoring tools might be usefull

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mursalat - There are many things you can do to see what is going on at that time.  How many processes is php-fpm spawning at that time?  This could be something with your settings.

One way to check out what is going on by checking the contents of the log:

```
/var/log/php5-fpm.log
```

Another great tool that we use is [NewRelic.](http://newrelic.com) You should be able to get a free trial while you debug the issues you may be having.

Last but not least, are you sure this is not normal behavior?  How much memory is php-fpm actually using?